# Why can't I use asset path helpers with sass-rails and the asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, asset-pipeline, compass-sass

I'm upgrading an app from Rails 3.0 to 3.1. We've been using Compass and scss.

I'm getting an error when I do **both** of the following:

- Use a `sass-rails` helper, like `image-path`
- Use `config.sass.load_paths` in `application.rb` to tell it where to find things like Blueprint.

For example:

```
config.sass.load_paths << "#{Gem.loaded_specs['compass'].full_gem_path}/frameworks/compass/stylesheets"
config.sass.load_paths << "#{Gem.loaded_specs['compass'].full_gem_path}/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets"
```

The error that I get is like:

```
undefined local variable or method `config' for #<Sass::Script::Functions::EvaluationContext::0x00000105102998>
```

I have this in my Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier',     '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'compass',      '0.11.5'
end
```

... which is exactly what is generated by Rails 3.1.1.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is solved by using Compass 0.12. I updated my Gemfile to use this:

```
gem 'compass', '0.12.alpha.1'
```

This also makes the `config.sass.load_paths` directives unnecessary.